# How to make a file extension downloadable?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, download

I'm trying to download http://www.downway1.com/dota/eng/DotA%20Allstars%20v6.67.w3x this file. But it's not able to download. It's opening unknown text. How I can set it up? Maybe I can use htaccess? but how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can download it with google chrome and opera, so probably it's a browser related issue.
Anyway, add to your .htaccess the following :

```
AddType application/octet-stream .w3x
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also make use of headers:

```
<?php
 // outputting the file
 header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');

 // It will be called DotA Allstars v6.67.w3x
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="DotA Allstars v6.67.w3x"');

 // The source file
 readfile('DotA Allstars v6.67.w3x');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`AddType` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) to set the type for the `.w3x` file extension:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .w3x
```

The [*application/octet-stream* media type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.5.1) is defined to describe arbitrary binary data and clients should not open it directly but download it.